# getMany from a TypeORM Repository instead of just one

Tags: typescript, backend, typeorm

I have this code that gets a single book from the TypeORM repository and it works fine.

```
public async getBook(name: string) {
    const book = this.bookRepository.findOne({
      where: [{ name: name }],
    });
    return book;
  }
```

However, I want to implement some sort of GetManyBooks where I take in a list of names as strings use the find keyword instead of findone and return it. I thought it would be similar, but I'm having trouble finding any documentation online about this.

```
public async getManyBooks(name: string[]) {
    const book = this.bookRepository.find({
      where: [{ name: name }],
    });
    return book;
  }
```

Is there a better way I should be tackling this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `in` operator proivided by typeorm. [Here are the docs](https://orkhan.gitbook.io/typeorm/docs/find-options)

Also I recommend you dont use `async` since you dont use `await` and instead just return the promise itself. This will give you a `Promise<Book[]>`.

```js
import { In } from "typeorm";

// docs example

const loadedPosts = await connection.getRepository(Post).find({
    title: In(["About #2", "About #3"]),
});


// In your case

public getManyBooks(name: string[]) {
    return this.bookRepository.find({
        where: {name: In(name)},
    });
}
```